# Descargar archivo PDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

> Jquery

Se envia la información de los `inputText`:

**Botón enviar:**

```
$.ajax({
  data:{
  "alumno":$("#txt_nombre").val(),
  "matricula":$("#txt_matricula").val(),
  "carrera":$("#txt_carrera").val(),
  "grupo":"ewq",
  "celular":$("#txt_celular").val(),
  "email":$("#txt_email").val(),
  "nivel":$("#sel_modulo").val(),
  "pago":$("#sel_pago").val(),
  "grupo_ins":$("#sel_grupo").val(),
  "horario":$("#txt_horasi").val(),
  "docente":$("#txt_docasi").val(),

},
  url:"php/format_f.php",
  type:"POST",
  beforeSend: function(){

  },
    success:function(vista){
        Mensaje("verde","correctamennte enviado");
    }
});
```

> Archivo format_f.php

```
    <?php
  ob_start();

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>ResultadoEXAM</title>
    </head>
    <body style="">
        <img src="formatos/header.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
        <center><h3>INSTITUCION</h3>
      <h4>XXXXX</h4>
      <h4>XXXXX</h4>
      <h3>XXXXX</h3></center>

      <center><img src="formatos/icono.png" style="width:80px;" /></center>
      <br><br>

        <h5>FICHA DE INSCRIPCIÓN DEL “YYYYY“ </h5>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;">DATOS DEL ALUMNO</h5><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;">Fecha: <?php $_POST['fecha'];?></h5>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;"><strong>Nombre:</strong> <?php $_POST['alumno'] ?><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;"><strong>Matricula:</strong> <?php $_POST['matricula'];?></h5>
        <br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;"><strong>Carrera:</strong> <?php $_POST['carrera']?><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;"><strong>Grupo:</strong> <?php $_POST['grupo'];?></h5>
        <br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;"><strong>Celular:</strong> <?php $_POST['celular'] ?><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;"><strong>E-Mail:</strong> <?php $_POST['email'];?></h5>
        <br><br>
        <h5><strong>Nivel a cursar:</strong> <?php $_POST['nivel'];?></h5>
        <h5><strong>Forma de pago:</strong> <?php $_POST['pago'];?></h5>
        <br><br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;">DATOS DE HORARIO Y GRUPO</h5><br>
        <h5><strong>Grupo inscrito:</strong> <?php $_POST['grupo_ins'];?></h5>
        <h5><strong>Horario seleccionado:</strong> <?php $_POST['horario'];?></h5>
        <h5><strong>Docente asignado:</strong> <?php $_POST['docente'];?></h5>

        <br><br><br><br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;">_____________________</h5><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;">_____________________</h5>
        <br>
        <h5 style="position:absolute; left:0;">Firma alumno</h5><h5 style="position:absolute; right:0;">Coordinadora de idiomas</h5>

<footer style="position:absolute; bottom:0;">
  <img src="formatos/footer.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
</footer>
    </body>
    <style media="screen">
    *{
      font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    strong{
      color:#999;
      font-style: oblique;
    }
        h4,h5{
          margin:0px;
        }
        h3{
          margin:15px;
          font-size:25px;
        }
        h4{
          color:#555;
          font-size:15px;
        }
        h5{
          font-size:18px;
          font-weight: 100;
        }
    </style>
  </html>
  <?php
  require_once ("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
  $dompdf->render();
  $pdf=$dompdf->output();
  $filename = 'nombre.pdf';
  $dompdf->stream($filename, array("Attachment" => 1));
 ?>
```

Aquí supuestamente debería estar recibiendo la información y generar el formato de PDF, el problema es que no descarga el archivo. Simplemente no hace nada al precionar el boton de *enviar*
*Ojo! utilizo la libreria de dompdf para generar el archivo.*

Comment: Prueba a usar window.open() en la promesa.

Comment: ya lo he puesto en **success:function** de ajax. pero aun así no resulta nada.